# Inserting dynamic column into website table?

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working on a website that contains a table with 12 columns that displays various information about students in each row. I'm trying to add a 13th column that displays either `PASS`, `FAIL`, or leaves it `BLANK` if the student hasn't written the exam yet.

In my MSSQL database I have two tables. T1 (Students) contains various information about the student and has a keyId (primary key) which is what the website table is using to group rows together by student. Once the student wrote the exam, he is assigned a student number in the same table (if not it is `NULL`). This student number is the primary key in the second table that has either a value of `PASS` or `FAIL` attached to it.

EDIT: The data PASS or FAIL in the second table is inserted through the website on another tab where the teacher inputs the student number and chooses either pass or fail.

The data type of the Status column (pass or fail) is enum(string) P & F.

```
<?php 

$objMSSQL = new cMSSQL(); 

//[...] 

for($i = 0; $i < $noOfRows; $i++)
    $noOfRows = $objMSSQL->getAffectedRows();

//[...]

$examStatus = $objMSSQL->getTable("
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Students] 
    INNER JOIN [Exams] ON Exams.studentNo = Students.studentNo
")

if ($examStatus[$i][Status] == 'PASS')
    echo '<td width="80px"> PASS </td>';
elseif ($examStatus[$i][Status] == 'FAIL')
    echo '<td width="80px"> FAIL </td>';
else
    echo '<td width="80px"></td>';

?>
```

I've been searching endlessly for a solution and just cant figure out why it isn't displaying correctly on the website (it's displaying pass or fail seemingly randomly and leaving nothing blank).

Comment: What specifically have you tried to debug your problem?

Comment: Sorry Aaron, I don't quite understand your question (remember I am somewhat of a beginner at this).

Comment: You said "I've been searching endlessly for a solution". Would you describe in more detail what you looked for, what you found, and why it did not solve your problem.

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting downvoted. I am obviously new to this site (which I love btw), so if I am doing something wrong or missing some information or code just let me know, please.

Comment: See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/default.aspx

Comment: Searching endlessly by researching w3, this website and others looking for solutions. I assume there is a problem with my SQL query? I have been trying different methods for days of making this work which is why im trying to use the "if" method of filling the table data now. In terms of debugging, my experience is limited so I am trying different SQL queries and such to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Would you post 1. Some sample data  2. The output you are expecting 3. The output you actually get.

Comment: If your PASS and FAIL data is in a database column associated with a student ID, you don't need this if-else statement.  You need to just create the php code that will generate the html you plan to use with the database field names/variables

Comment: @Aaron Kurtzhals What is the best way to go about this? Simply explain or you need an SQL fiddle or something.

Comment: @N1tr0 This makes sense. Could you please link me or show me what this looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  I've copied in your code from above and added the piece you need using the appropriate function. (tweak/edit/rename as needed to get to work/display correctly).

Here is another example:  [Creating a dynamic table with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885871/creating-a-dynamic-table-with-php)

You can use this as an example to create your dynamic table in PHP:

```
<?php 

$objMSSQL = new cMSSQL(); 

//[...] 

for($i = 0; $i < $noOfRows; $i++)
    $noOfRows = $objMSSQL->getAffectedRows();

//[...]

$examStatus = $objMSSQL->getTable("
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Students] 
    INNER JOIN [Exams] ON Exams.studentNo = Students.studentNo
")

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       print '<tr>'
      .'<td>' . $row['col1'] . '</td>'
      .'<td>' . $row['col2'] . '</td>'
      .'<td>' . $row['col3'] . '</td>'
      .'<td>' . $row['colx'] . '</td>'
      .'</tr>';
}

?>
```

So it's basically looping through your query results.  Since you are joining on your Students table, you will have access to the PASS/FAIL data.  You will probably want to not use '*' but instead list out what columns you want from each table.

Now, I'm not certain the rest of your code is correct or what you need (i.e. FOR loop), the WHILE loop is needed to create the table and output the data.

Comment: I have something similar for my website but use ECHO instead of PRINT.

Comment: Is this the same if I'm using MS SQL Server?

Comment: It's very similar.  Here a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, you can add in your 13 column there. Something like:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN EXAM_SCORE > 70.00 then 'PASS'
               WHEN EXAM_SCORE < 70.00 then 'FAIL'
               else ''
               END EXAM_SCORE as PassFail
FROM [Students] INNER JOIN [Exams] ON Exams.studentNo=Students.studentNo
```

Comment: Since I don't know your table structures I just made up a column name but you get the idea. :-).  Not sure how you are determining PASS or FAIL.

Comment: It is not related to the grade, on another tab of the website the teacher inputs the student number and either clicks PASS or FAIL. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to add this functionality to your question up top so people can approach it from the right angle.

Comment: After reading your edit, I think my example should still work for you (or something like it).  If the data is in the second table, why can't you select it out?

Comment: This is where my problem lies and my lack of experience keeps me blocked. PASS or FAIL is in the second table, but in the website pass or fail needs to be related to the students keyId (in order to be in the correct row). The keyId is only available in the first table. Through the website, a student number is entered with either pass or fail, which is inserted into the second table. This student number is the only thing found in both tables (once inserted in the second table, theres a column where the student has NULL but now becomes the student number, so its basically a reference).

Comment: It sounds like you just need to make your query a JOIN between the two tables.

Comment: @Barmar I will try this and let you know how it went

Answer (score 0):

if you require a variable / dynamic number of columns, you should look into vertical table layout