# How to dynamically populate exact amount of TD on each TR element in table?

Tags: php

I am working on the below code. How can I force to have 5 `td` in each `tr` until the end of the loop?

```
<?php
$countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cruise Ship","Cuba","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kuwait","Kyrgyz Republic","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Namibia","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Satellite","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","South Africa","South Korea","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","St. Lucia","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];


echo '<table>';
 foreach ($countries as $country){
   echo '<tr><td>'.$country.'</td></tr>';
 }
echo '</table>';

    ?>
```

As you can see I am able to add each item to one row but I need to have 5 in each and last one no matter how many will be (for sure less than 5).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a dynamic table with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885871/creating-a-dynamic-table-with-php)

Comment: This is a Pure HTML table that post is about creating MySQL Table , have ever read the post at all?!

Comment: No, the other post is not about create a MySQL table.  It's about creating an HTML table using PHP.  Hence, the possible duplicate flag.  P.S.  Please keep your rudeness to yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally close and open tr when the index is divisible by 5 like below

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($countries as $k=>$country){
    if($k%5 ==0 && $k!=0){
       echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo '<td>'.$country.'</td>';
 }
echo "</tr>";
echo '</table>';
```

**But I will recommend you to solve this using div or lists with css techniques which is better solution**